$\phi^3,\phi^4$ theory Feynman diagram
I know how to calculate the Feynman diagrams for $\phi^4$ theory or a $\phi^3$ theory. But what will the Feynman diagram look like in a theory like:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\phi)^2-\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2-\frac{\mu \sqrt{\lambda}}{3!}\phi^3-\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4
\end{align*}
Here, $\phi(x)$ is the real scalar field.
What changes will be made in the Feynman rules in this theory?

The Feynman rules will be exactly the same as the ones you're familiar with, except you'll have both a cubic and quartic vertex instead of just one or the other, and so generically more diagrams will contribute to a given amplitude.
